# При наведении курсора на блок он меняет бекграунд

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении курсора на блок, он менял beckground. Блок простой - div. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

CSS (не уверен в IE)

```
div {background:#fff;}
div:hover {background:#000;}
```

JS

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.background='#000';" onmouseout="this.style.background='#fff';">
```

Comment: спасибо,всё работает

Comment: а может вы знаете еще как сделать что бы при наведении на ссылку,вокруг ссылки образовалось маленькое поле(типо кнопки что ли).ВОт как на этом сайте внизу http://webmolot.com/recipe/css/element6

Comment: Аналогично. Прочитайте в CSS про hover
<code>
a {background:#fff;}
a:hover {background:#000;}
</code>